# Python API makes a db call SQL Query Efficiency between = vs IN operator for multiple values

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm currently working on making a database call from the API and I would like to determine the most efficient approach between the following two:

**Multiple queries using the = operator**

```
select employee_name from employee where employee_id = 123;
select employee_name from employee where employee_id = 456;
select employee_name from employee where employee_id = 789;
```

**Single query with in operator**

```
select employee_name from employee where employee_id in(123, 456, 789);
```

The target database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a no-brainer that Query with IN operator is efficient and provides better performance as compared to individual queries, and this is irrespective of any database that you use.

As you pointed out correctly, The main issue with separate queries is those are executed individually and result in 3 separate round trips from the database which is not great. (Total time includes the time it takes to reach till database server and actual processing for the resultset.)

This is definitely not the case in a query with IN operator because it is a single query to the database. (Plus query plan can be optimized for single query with IN operator)

Hope this helps.